# What is difference between these two statements?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

```
     var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        tr[0].onmouseover = function(){
          tr[0].style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'; 
        }
        tr[1].onmouseover = function(){
          tr[1].style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'; 
        }
        tr[2].onmouseover = function(){
          tr[2].style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'; 
        }
```

The first is right, but when I use a `for` loop as in the following code snippet, I get "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`".

```
     var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for(var i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
          tr[i].onmouseover = function(){
            tr[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'; 
          }            
        }
```

Comment: This would be easy enough to debug. Place a breakpoint in your debugger on the line where you are setting the background color. Press on the first `tr`. Then examine the value of `i`. That should provide with an idea of what the problem is.

Comment: To sum up, you cannot use `i` after the loop has completed (such as inside of a callback). Best to have a `this` or `event` in the handler so that it can look up its DOM element by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update from

```
 tr[i].onmouseover = function(){
    tr[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'; 
 }
```

to

```
 tr[i].onmouseover = function(event){
    event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc'; 
 }
```

Problem - By the time you were trying to access `tr[i]` in the event handler value of `i` was updated to 3 and hence the error occured

Comment: IIRC `window.event` is IE-specific. The normal approach is to write the handler to take an `event` parameter.

Comment: @torazaburo - Yes you are correct. I just hurried on to the answer and made a mess of it.

Comment: got it .thanks a lot.